# "CalledProcessError" When I am trying to read the .pdf tables

Tags: java, python

CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF8', '-jar', 'C:\Users\vijv2c13136\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tabula\tabula-1.0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar', '--pages', 'all', '--guess', '--format', 'JSON', 'resumes\AbhinavReddy.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 2

I have tried many solutions. But, Those didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

```
 print(wrapper.read_pdf("D:/PdfTableReader/adi.pdf", multiple_tables=True,pages="all"))
```

Comment: can you add the code which caused this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be related to not having installed the (correct version of) the java runtime.

See also [this github post](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/issues/60).

Instructions for installing java can be found [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/download_options.xml).

Comment: Should I need to set environment for java?

Comment: Thank for a lot. I was updated my java version to latest. It was working correctly

Comment: Then please mark this answer as the accepted answer, so other people know the problem can indeed be solved like this.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same error, but the reason was different. In my case it was not a java problem, because other files are read perfectly.

The issue was in the filename!

My file was called `PROMOCIOěN.pdf`

That `ě` was causing the error. I removed that char from the filename, and everything worked fine.